# How to calculate sum of values in each column based on row names in R?

Tags: r

I can do this in python but in R I cannot find how to do conditions.

I have a matrix with colnames(mat), rownames(mat). For each column, I need to calculate sum of values if a row begins from a certain pattern. Let's say I need to sum up only the values where the row name starts from 'A'.

I tried this:

```
for(i in  colnames(mat)) {
  sum_A=0
  for (j in rownames(mat)) {
    sum_A<-sum(mat[ j == 'A^', i])
  }
}

A
```

It gives me this output:

```
[1] 0
```

Comment: I guess you need `grepl`.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected ouptut.   `colSums(mat[starts_with(row.names(mat), "A"),])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colSums` with `startsWith`

```
colSums(mat[startsWith(row.names(mat), "A"),])
```